# orderBy in angularjs in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby

I don't understand why it's not working do you have an idea why `orderBy'-nbtickets'` not working ?

```
  <ul ng-repeat="item in customarray | orderBy:'-nbtickets' track by $index">
    <li ui-sref="app.usersingle({id:item[0].id,iterate:1})" class="row organization">
      <div class="col-md-2 classement text-center">{{$index+1}}</div>
      <div class="name col-md-4 text-center">{{item[0].username}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 total text-center">{{item[0].nbtickets}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 maintenance text-center">{{item[0].tickmaintenance}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-2 assistance text-center">{{item[0].tickassistance}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

in my controler i just do that:

`$scope.customarray = data;`

Here the array i display it by doing {{item}}(parse of my array which is preatty big)

```
[
  {"username":"Eugenie Martin","tickassistance":4,"tickbug":0,"tickmaintenance":3,"nbtickets":7,"id":660302971,"tickets":[{"date":"2015-09-29T07:12:14Z","titre":"Changement date de clôture dossier Barbe Alain","status":"closed","tag":"maintenance"},
  {"date":"2015-09-04T09:45:20Z","titre":"43325- NH DISTRIBUTION","status":"closed","tag":"assistance"},
  {"date":"2015-08-20T06:18:04Z","titre":"TR: EURL NH DISTRIBUTION vous a envoyé un message depuis sa plateforme","status":"closed","tag":"assistance"},{"date":"2015-02-25T16:00:46Z","titre":"Votre demande au support sans suite","status":"closed","tag":"assistance"},
  {"date":"2015-01-12T06:48:35Z","titre":"Bonjour,\n\nle cabinet AUFICOM aura un stand lors du...","status":"closed","tag":"assistance"},
  {"date":"2014-12-18T09:48:38Z","titre":"ISACOMPTA","status":"closed","tag":"maintenance"},{"date":"2014-12-15T14:08:08Z","titre":"changement date de clôture","status":"closed","tag":"maintenance"}],
  "monthly":[{"now11":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now10":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now9":1,"assist":1,"maint":0},
  {"now8":2,"assist":1,"maint":1},
  {"now7":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now6":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now5":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now4":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now3":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now2":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now1":0,"assist":0,"maint":0},
  {"now":0,"assist":0,"maint":0}]},
  [{"date":"2015-09-29T07:12:14Z","titre":"Changement date de clôture dossier Barbe Alain","status":"closed","tag":"maintenance","id":660302971,"name":"Eugenie Martin"},
  {"date":"2015-09-04T09:45:20Z","titre":"43325- NH DISTRIBUTION","status":"closed","tag":"assistance","id":660302971,"name":"Eugenie Martin"},
  {"date":"2015-08-20T06:18:04Z","titre":"TR: EURL NH DISTRIBUTION vous a envoyé un message depuis sa plateforme","status":"closed","tag":"assistance","id":660302971,"name":"Eugenie Martin"},
  {"date":"2015-02-25T16:00:46Z","titre":"Votre demande au support sans suite","status":"closed","tag":"assistance","id":660302971,"name":"Eugenie Martin"},
  {"date":"2015-01-12T06:48:35Z","titre":"Bonjour,\n\nle cabinet AUFICOM aura un stand lors du...","status":"closed","tag":"assistance","id":660302971,"name":"Eugenie Martin"},
  {"date":"2014-12-18T09:48:38Z","titre":"ISACOMPTA","status":"closed","tag":"maintenance","id":660302971,"name":"Eugenie Martin"},
  {"date":"2014-12-15T14:08:08Z","titre":"changement date de clôture","status":"closed","tag":"maintenance","id":660302971,"name":"Eugenie Martin"}]
];
```

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: @Stark Buttowski You want the JSON array or the controller code ?

Comment: if both means, easy to get solution

Comment: You should also define "not working". But seeing this code, it seems nbtickets is a property of item[0], not a property of item.

Comment: @JB Nizet And how could i call it with item[0] ?, when i say it's not not is that i didn t have error in console but it is not oder by `nbtickets`

Comment: There is no `nbtickets` property for other objects except for the first one. Pls check your array and its objects

Comment: i just show you the first object of array so it's normal you see only one `nbtickets`property because my array is pretty big

Comment: You didn't explain it well enough. This problems are very easy to fix, but without clear problem description this question will likely remain unanswered. If you want help, make sure you describe the problem well.

Comment: I don't know how to explain what i can say is just my list i display in my view is not sort by `nbtickets`, what i want is a list sort by `nbtickets`order is that clear ?

Comment: I think the problem here is that you are using strange data structure. For example I can't tell why it is structured this way (`[{}, [{}, {}, {}]]`), so it's hard for me to help here.

Comment: @moskitos I agree with dfsq: the structure of your objects is a mess. Transform this 2-elements array into an object with two fields: `user`, which ise the user with its username, its nbtickets, its tickets, etc., and `logs`, which is the second element of the array. Then user `orderBy: 'user.nbtickets'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in customarray | orderBy:'nbtickets':true track by $index">
```

There is a reverse option in angular `orderBy` which is the `:true` part above.

Comment: Just i make it by doing this: `orderBy:item[0].nbtickets:true`

Comment: @cfz42 where's your declaration for the reverse?

Comment: @thepio the `-` right after orderBy: is equivalent to appending `:true`. Also, the `reverse` option is not `ng-repeat` specific but it's an `orderBy` option which can also be used outside the html. Moreover, the snippet you provided didn't solve the question since you're ordering by `nbtickets` which obviously doesn't do what op's expects. Sorry but you basically rewrote the question with a different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `orderBy:-item[0].nbtickets` ?

Comment: Well the idea is here because it's working but not in the reverse way if like i it's order like that : 2,3,4 and i want 4,3,2 do you have an idea ?

Comment: `orderBy:item[0].nbtickets` ?